# Word styling tips

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to add some references in a word document, but i wish to add them as [1] author, Paper, [2]...., [3]....., but the counting numbers to be generated automaticaly in this format.

Do you have any idea, about how can be made this?

I'm using MS word 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word can add automatically numbered end references, either at the foot of the page, or at the end of the document easily enough.

From the "Insert" pull down menu choose "reference" then "Footnote" and go from there.

Your example shows the numbers in square brackets - I do not think Word can format the reference numbers this way automatically. If you have the patience, you can type the brackets around the reference number and format them as a super script - From the "Format" pull down menu choose font, and check "superscript"